Non-admin users cannot run reports
This issue seemed to arrive out of the blue. We have a japserserver install that is accessed via non-admin users.   About a week ago we started getting security errors when these users run reports.
I've tried giving users admin permissions to the reports but the same error occurs.
The stack trace is
2024-08-20 13:33:33,946 ERROR SecureExceptionHandlerImpl,ajp-nio-8009-exec-8:116 - There was an error on the server. Try again or contact site administrators. (Error UID: 20ee7af6-12a2-490d-b6dd-1dce008c9253)
2024-08-20 13:33:33,947 ERROR Error PageHandlerAction,ajp-nio-8009-exec-8:118 - Error UID 20ee7af6-12a2-490d-b6dd-1dce008c9253
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.security.access.Access DeniedException: Access is denied
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.checkForParams (ViewReportAction.java:293)
at sun.reflect.Generated MethodAccessor637.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Has anyone dealt with this before?   We're running on EC2.
Tried assignn admin permissions no luck.  Only runs for the overall server admin.
